# Cannot import VTODO to Reminders app on MacOS Ventura 13.1

Tags: calendar, ical, reminders, ventura

I'm trying to import an ics file containing only todos (VTODO) to Apple reminders app.

Since the App doesn't provide an option to import todos, I use the calendar app; File > Import > ICS file.

I get this error: reminders app cannot open the specified document or URL.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:todo
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Paris
BEGIN:VTODO
LAST-MODIFIED:20230121T101517Z
DTSTAMP:20230121T101517Z
UID:uid4@example.com
SUMMARY:My todo
PRIORITY:1
CATEGORIES:WORK
DUE:20230121T235959
X-MOZ-GENERATION:2
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

This file is using CRLF line feeds.

Even with a minimal file that respects the spec here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545 it doesn't work.

Is there anyone that manages to import todos to the reminders App?

OS version: MacOS Ventura 13.1 on M1 Mac (ARM)